# Search doesn't return results in Django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am recently building a web app backend with Django-rest-framework.

I am trying to build a search functionality where the user will type in a location name and all results that contain the name will be displayed.

I am using icontains and Q. My test search view is as below:

```
class test_search(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class =  customer_location
        title = json.loads(request.body).get('title')
        queryset = Customers.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=title))
        data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I am able to see a page which asks me to enter the location name but when I enter the name and click POST nothing happens. I want to display the values present in the Customer model, customer_location serializer which match the location name.

I am using icontains as I want to return all values which contain it.

What am I doing wrong? How to display the matched results?

When I try this -

```
class test_search(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = customer_location
        title = request.query_params.get('title')
        queryset = Customers.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=title))
        data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
        return Response(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I get this error -

```
ValueError at /test_search/
Cannot use None as a query value
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_search/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Cannot use None as a query value
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in build_lookup, line 1121
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
```

When I check in Postman it displays the results. Why does it not display the result from the api endpoin/url ?

Comment: The snippet you provided seems incomplete. You neither return response from the post method nor call super. Serializer class seems unused. Please provide complete example.

Comment: I edited the code. I am very new to django. I am able to view the result in postman but the api end point doesn't give back the same result.

Comment: Q object isnt necessary here, you can omit it. Still serializer_class isn't initialised. Try returning regular Response from DRF without casting data to str.

Comment: I removed Q and str casting. I still face the same issue.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by not seeing result in the api endpoint but being able to see result in Postman? Please update your code so that it is a working snippet.

Comment: when I use the api end point in postman and try sending a location name I get the list of response. But in the browser when I type in the end point and post the location name it does not display anything. It just shows get method not allowed.

Comment: It is because accessing your endpoint url from the browser makes GET request which is not implemented. You should implement get method for such operations like filtering your database and getting results. POST is not meant for filtering.

Comment: I am using a post because the location name has to be entered by the user. Can I use post and get in the same class? How can I do that ? I am a noob at django

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because accessing your endpoint url from the browser makes GET request which is not implemented. You should implement get method for such operations like filtering your database and getting results. POST is not meant for filtering.

Implement get method  instead of post in the way you implemented post.

Your user can enter location value even if it is GET because HTML forms can be submitted as POST or GET. GET is default submission method if you do not set it in html form element.

Comment: how can I implement get to do the same thing as post in my case? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I get this error when I replace post with get -
JSONDecodeError at /test_search/
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_search/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: JSONDecodeError
Exception Value: 
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Exception Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode, line 355
Python Executable: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

Comment: Access title like so: `title = request.query_params.get('title')`

Comment: I get this error now - ValueError at /test_search/
Cannot use None as a query value
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_search/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Cannot use None as a query value
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in build_lookup, line 1121
Python Executable: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7

Comment: It looks like you don't pass a title parameter: 

Enter `127.0.0.1:8000/test_search?title=your_title` and change logic so that it returns all results if parameter is not passed:

```
if title:
    queryset = Customers.objects.filter(title__icontains=title)
else:
    queryset = Customers.objects.all()
```

Comment: I don't want to return everything if there is no match. I want the users to see an empty page with an option to pass a location name and then the results that match should be displayed. I tried to enter ```127.0.0.1:8000/test_search?title=your_title```. It returns some weird html data :(